# Расшарить пост в ВК, ОК, ФБ из iOS и Android

Tags: java, android, ios, objective-c

Добрый день.
Может кто подсказать самый простой способ шаринга в указанные соц сети поста из Android и iOS приложения без прямого подключения SDK соц сетей?
Приложения нативные.

Comment: написать свой сдк. либо открывать веб страницу авторизации

Answer (score 1):

1. Вот специальная библиотека для работы с неявными интентами https://github.com/marvinlabs/android-intents
2. Вот описание работы интентов от Гугла https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html
3. Вот англоязыная статья подробная на эту тему 
   https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-implement-a-share-intent--mobile-8433

Надеюсь, это поможет вам.

Comment: С интентами все понятно, но если этих приложений нет на устройстве?

Comment: Шарить нельзя без авторизации, а если приложений нет, то и авторизации нет.

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто использовать UIActivityViewController для iOS.

Answer (score 0):

**iOS:**

С FB проще всего, у UIActivityViewController есть список встроенных activityType, куда по умолчанию входит FB.

С ВК посложнее, или нативную SDK использовать и её обертки, или есть удобная обертка Simplicity для авторизации: 
[ссылка на Simplicity](https://github.com/SimplicityMobile/Simplicity)

С ОК - только нативную SDK использовать. Оберток не найдено.